# Cannot set a checkbox unchecked once it has been checked against the data with Vue

Tags: vue.js, checkbox, v-model

I am desparately trying to understand what's wrong there and can't figure it out!
I'll try to explain as best as I can, but the code is lengthy and I can't post it easily.

I have a component called "FrameHeader" that includes an input checkbox. This component is called in another component called "Frame", and the frames made from a v-for in another component ("FrameContainer").

In FrameHeader template, I have this:

```
<input :key="'frame-touchselectbox-'+frameId" type="checkbox" 
  v-model="touchSelected"
  :class="{hidden: !isTouchSelectOn, selectCheckBox: true}"        
/>
```

touchSelected is a computed property defined as such:

```
computed: {        
        touchSelected() {
            console.log("checking frame touch selected for frame " + this.frameId + " ==> " + store.getters.isFrameTouchSelected(this.frameId));
            return store.getters.isFrameTouchSelected(this.frameId);
        },
    },
```

where store.getters.isFrameTouchSelected(this.frameId); retrieves a boolean property called "touchSelected" in an object of the state:

The idea is that in the scenario I have, all "touchSelected" properties are first set to false (A), then only the one from one of the frame is set to true (B).

(A):

```
toggleTouchSelect(state, payload: {frameId: number; toggle: boolean}) {
            const newCandidates: number[] = (payload.toggle) ? getAllSiblings(state.frameObjects, payload.frameId): [];
            Object.keys(state.frameObjects).forEach((frameKey) => {
                Vue.set(
                    state.frameObjects[parseInt(frameKey)],
                    "touchSelected",
                    false
                );
                Vue.set(
                    state.frameObjects[parseInt(frameKey)],
                    "isTouchSelectOn",
                    newCandidates.includes(parseInt(frameKey))
                );
            });
        },
```

(B):

```
touchSelectFrame(state, payload: {frameId: number; isSelected: boolean}) {
            Vue.set(
                state.frameObjects[payload.frameId],
                "touchSelected",
                payload.isSelected
            );
        },
```

The data I get in the store **is** correct, I get false/true values where I want them.

However, the checkboxes are not correct. The first time I set one of the frame's property to "true", the corresponding checkbox gets checked. But when I get another frame's property to "true", the previous frame's checkbox doesn't get unchecked. Actually, I see it first being unchecked, then being checked again.

As I said, the data in the state is correct: even when that checkbox revert to checked, the underlying property in the data for that frame is "false".

BUT the weirdest thing is that if only change the checkbox input to a text input (changing the type of the input in the template), the text value is always correct even after the second time I set a frame's property to "true".

So...i'm totally puzzled and can't understand what's happening with those checkboxes.
Sorry for the vague explanation I hope it can still be understandable and that someone will shed a light on that :) Thanks a lot.

Comment: don't use `v-model` with readonly `computed` prop. Either change `v-model` to `:value` or define computed prop with a getter and a setter

Comment: @Anatoly I guess you meant ":checked" as it's a checkbox? I've tried it but the behaviours stays the same. (with ":value", the checkboxes never get checked at all).

Answer (score 1):

Computed props are by default getter-only ([reference](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter)). That means your checkbox can read the value of `touchSelected` but can't change its value. You have to use a computed prop with a getter **AND** a setter. Assuming you have a mutation to change your `frameId` logic in Vuex:

```
computed: {        
  touchSelected: {
    get(): {
      return store.getters.isFrameTouchSelected(this.frameId);
    }
    set(newValue): {
      store.commit('FRAME_MUTATION', newValue);
    }
  }
},
```

Comment: I know that computed values are by default getter only. But I don't understand here what is the role of a setter. For the moment at least, I don't need to take action when the user actually checks or unchecks the checkbox, so if I only programmatically set a value for the checkbox (via store.getters.isFrameTouchSelected(this.frameId)), is the computed property required for something at all? 

The way I understand the role of the setter here is when the checkbox value is changed by the user. Am I wrong?

Thank you

Comment: If you just want to READ the value of `store.getters.isFrameTouchSelected(this.frameId))` then you may want to add a normal data prop to your Vue instance with a intial value of `store.getters.isFrameTouchSelected(this.frameId))`. This way you don't need a computed prop at all.

Comment: I found the cause of my problem. It's not about the data binding, but what happens in the flow to change the data in store, that seems to interact in some weird way with the checkbox. Thanks a lot though for your help.
(ps for information, I was changing the data in store via a directive I use on the parent component (Frame), and that directive is from the package called vue-directive-long-press)

Comment: Good luck then.